# Sample WebService url to get and post values like email and password from android

Tags: android, web-services, webserver, http-post, android-volley

I want a sample **WebService URL**, which can be used to practice android networking with volley.

I know there are many sample URLs which send `Json` data but I want a **WebService URL** which accepts and store data (may be in MySql Database) like(email,password) sent by android app.

I want to practice these things but I have not found required setup for this,
if such type of free **WebService** is not available then please suggest me how can I practice android networking, specially Posting data to server (usually used in user signup and sign-in)

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you want to practice Networking

Webservice Type : REST

Returns a list of cities and placenames in the bounding box, ordered by relevancy (capital/population). Placenames close together are filterered out and only the larger name is included in the resulting list.

JSON URL : 
[Click here](http://api.geonames.org/citiesJSON?north=44.1&south=-9.9&east=-22.4&west=55.2&lang=de&username=demo)

Same output in XML format :-

XML URL : [Click here](http://api.geonames.org/cities?north=44.1&south=-9.9&east=-22.4&west=55.2&username=demo)

Comment: Thanks Nishu, these URLs will be usefull for me, but would be better if you provide me URLs which accept parameters and store them